# Show the popads code only in mobile devices, how to do that?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable popups for mobile visitors, how can i do that?

Is it possible to change the popads.net adcode in order to not show popups in mobile visitors?

```js
<!-- PopAds - Home Popunder Code for Official lap times from Auto Magazines & Manufacturers | 2016-12-13,1627132,0,0 -->

<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">

//<![CDATA[

(function(){ var f=window;f["\x5f\x70o\x70"]=[["\x73iteI\u0064",1627132],["\x6di\u006eBi\u0064",0],["\x70\x6fp\u0075nd\x65r\x73\x50\x65\u0072\u0049\x50",0],["\u0064el\u0061y\u0042\u0065\x74w\u0065\u0065n",0],["de\u0066au\x6ct",false],["de\u0066\u0061\u0075\u006c\x74\x50\u0065\u0072\u0044\x61\u0079",0],["t\x6f\x70m\u006fstLaye\u0072",!0]];var m=["\u002f/c1.\x70o\x70\u0061\u0064\x73\x2e\u006e\x65\u0074/\u0070\u006fp\x2e\x6as","\x2f\u002fc\u0032.p\u006f\u0070\x61\x64\u0073\u002en\x65\x74\u002f\x70\u006f\u0070\x2e\x6a\u0073","/\x2f\x77w\x77.\x69n\u0073b\x72\x76w\u0066r\x63\u0067b\u002e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\u0076\x75\u0074k.js","\x2f/\u0077\u0077\x77.\u006etn\x6c\x61w\x67c\u0068\x67ds\x2e\u0063\x6f\x6d/d\x2e\x6a\x73",""],t=0,j,g=function(){if(""==m[t])return;j=f["\u0064ocu\x6d\u0065nt"]["\x63\x72\u0065\x61\x74\u0065E\x6c\u0065\x6de\u006et"]("\u0073\x63r\x69\x70\x74");j["\x74\x79pe"]="\x74\u0065\u0078t/\x6a\u0061\x76\x61sc\x72\u0069p\u0074";j["\u0061\x73yn\x63"]=!0;var s=f["\x64\x6fc\x75me\x6e\x74"]["\x67\x65\u0074\u0045l\u0065\u006den\x74\u0073\u0042y\x54\x61\u0067\u004e\u0061\x6d\x65"]("s\u0063\x72\u0069\u0070\x74")[0];j["s\u0072\x63"]=m[t];if(t<2){j["c\u0072o\x73\x73\u004f\u0072\u0069\u0067\u0069\x6e"]="\x61n\u006fn\x79\x6do\x75\x73";};j["\u006fne\u0072ro\x72"]=function(){t++;g()};s["\u0070\u0061\u0072\x65\x6e\x74Nod\u0065"]["\u0069n\u0073\x65\u0072\u0074\u0042\x65f\x6fre"](j,s)};g()})();

//]]>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid browser checking by only running the ads when the [`screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) exceeds a certain size:

```js
if (screen.width > 800 || screen.height > 800) {
    // load some ads
    (function () {
        // paste your ad code here
    })()
} else {
    // do other stuff instead
}
```

If you want to check only the size of the *available* space on the `screen`, you can use the `availHeight` and `availWidth` properties instead.

Comment: Let me edit my post to show you exactly where to paste it.

Comment: No problem. An accept/upvote would always be appreciated if it helped :)

Comment: Well actually it didn't work, i have put the adcode where it says paste you ad code here, but it didn't work. I forgot to say that i put the adcode on the header, don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: You have to decide what qualifies as "mobile" -- I don't have a mobile browser handy, but you should check the screen width and screen height and then adjust the `800`s in the example above to numbers that fall below those values.

Comment: The problem is that when i publish the website, it shows some of the script you told me in header area and the popups still open on my mobile. Maybe i did something wrong, i don't know.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the HTML code so far? Thanks.

Comment: I have added the code for the popups, can you please change it to display only for desktop visitors?